# Intercepting the value change of SetChildIndex

Tags: winforms, compact-framework, panel

In a .NET CF-form i have multiple panels. I want to have a property that should always be informed about if a panel is in the front.

Can this be done using the GetChildIndex() method?

If yes, how do i intercept the change to SetChildIndex()?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For everybody who is interested for future use:

simply add a new event handler for the Paint event of each panel, for example:

```
panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);
panel2.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel2_Paint);
```

and in each of the event handlers just call a Method which retrieves the state of all the panels like so:

```
void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            GetPanelStates();

        }

        void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            GetPanelStates();
        }



        void GetPanelStates()
        {
            Panel2IsInFront = panel2.Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(panel2) == 0;
            Panel1IsInFront = panel1.Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(panel1) == 0;
        }
```